# htaccess: relative paths not working properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

First, what I am trying to achieve:
I am testing under the base http://example.com/subdir and this is where all subfolders , index.php and .htaccess are.

I have 3 groups of rules as shown in the .htaccess (extra rules removed):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Convert   item/edit/xx -> index.php?p=edit&id=xx
# Convert   item/remove/xx -> index.php?p=remove&id=xx
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/item [NC]
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^item/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$    index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

# Convert category/yyyy -> customer/pagination.php?category=yyyy

#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=([a-zA-Z\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^customer/category/([a-zA-Z\s]+)$     customer/pagination.php?category=$1  [NC,L]


# Convert action/about   -> index.php?p=about
# Convert action/terms   -> index.php?p=terms


#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^action/([a-z]+)$     index.php?p=$1  [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

The first problem I faced was the RewriteCond not working (giving Path not found), so it is commented out for the moment.
RewriteRule works fine with absolute path (e.g. RewriteRule ^action/([a-z]+)$     http://example.com/subdir/index.php?p=$1  [NC,L]), however this causes the browser to display the real URL therefore I'm trying to make it work with relative paths.
My issue is that after a first redirect the first part of the link on the left is added to the path, i.e. http://example.com/subdir becomes http://example.com/subdir/action after clicking action/about link.
Defining RewriteBase or prepending slashes to the URLs only makes things worse.
I will be grateful to an eagle-eyed expert who can spot the root cause of my problem.

Comment: I do not really understand the second part of your question. What would be an example URL that causes the error, what path would you like it to be redirected to, and what path is it actually redirected to?

Comment: The example URL is : http://example.com/subdir/action/about. When clicked, it redirects to the correct About page, however the path for the next request becomes http://example.com/subdir/action/. Therefore when you click ,say, action/terms link - the resulting url=http://example.com/subdir/action/action/terms. Note the extra "action" folder added to the path (I need to redirect to  http://example.com/subdir/index.php?p=terms). All links are relative BTW, e.g. action/about. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that `%{REQUEST_URI}` always includes the full path. So, your condition could be changed to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir/item [NC]
```

---

The second problem would actually not be solved using .htaccess. You just need to tell the browser what you want. So, you can use one of two methods.

1. Use the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element (which will apply to **all** relative URIs on the page):

   ```
   <base href="/subdir" />
   ```
2. Use a relative path to the URL shown in the browser:

   ```
   <a href="terms">Click here</a>
   ```

If you really wanted to solve the problem using .htaccess, the only real way to do so would be to remove the duplicated directory after it has been requested.

Comment: Many thanks, setting <base href.. > helped, though I had to change all header redirections in PHP to absolute paths to make all links work.  I'll post the complete code after I get #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ [NC] to work.